# can't get countdown timer to work

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have to set a countdown to the 15th of every month.  I'm able to successfully get the difference value needed to countdown to the 15th.  But after that I honestly don't know what I'm doing.

After calculating the difference, I calculate the days, hours, min, secs.

I get the error Cannot read property Days Null

```
export default React.createClass({
tick: function(){

var currentDate = new Date();
var date_till_15 = new Date()

if(currentDate.getDate() < 15){
    var days_till_15 = 15 - currentDate.getDate();
    date_till_15 = new Date(date_till_15.setDate(currentDate.getDate() + days_till_15 ));
}else if(currentDate.getDate() > 15){
    date_till_15 = new Date(date_till_15.setMonth(currentDate.getMonth() + 1));
    date_till_15 = new Date(date_till_15.setDate(15));
}
    var difference =  date_till_15 - currentDate;
    var daysLeft = 0, hoursLeft = 0, minutesLeft = 0, secondsLeft = 0;
    if(difference > 0){
        daysLeft = Math.floor( difference / (1000*60*60*24) );
        difference -= daysLeft * (1000*60*60*24);
        hoursLeft = Math.floor( difference / (1000*60*60) );
        difference -= hoursLeft * (1000*60*60);
        minutesLeft = Math.floor( difference / (1000*60) );
        difference -= minutesLeft * (1000*60);
        secondsLeft = Math.floor( difference/1000 );

      this.setState({
        days: daysLeft,
        hours: hoursLeft,
        minutes: minutesLeft,
        seconds: secondsLeft
      });
  } else {
        clearInterval( this.timeInterval );
        this.setState({expired: true});
    }
},

componentDidMount: function(){
    this.timeInterval = setInterval( this.tick.bind(this), 1000);
},

render() { 
    return <div> <div> this.state.days</div>

           </div>
}
```

Comment: What line of code is that error message pointing to?

Comment: JCD i updated my code.  I got rid of the error by doing this.state && ..... But now everything except for this.state.days returns 0

Comment: well that sounds like a different problem that needs a new post to answer :) when your question is answered you should accept the correct answer instead of just changing your original post. Make a new post.

Comment: I updated my post :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first time your component renders, `this.state` doesn't exist, which is why `this.state.days` throws that error. To solve this, you could either create an initial state, or only render the value if `this.state` exists:

```
render() { 
    return <div>{this.state && this.state.days}</div>
}
```

Comment: okay I got rid of the error with that.  Now everything returns 0 exept days.  Minutes, hrs, secs = 0. Will update my post

Comment: I'm just going to start a new post and accept this as the correct answer for this one. thanks